# pywin installed, but PythonWin cannot open

Tags: python, pywin32

I installed pywin from this [site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/). I used version pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.6.exe, and it installed without any error.

I am trying to automate use of a software. To do this, I am following a tutorial that says I need to select something from the Tools Menu in pywin. So I expected to find a program with a  GUI that I could open from the Windows Start Menu.

However, although I see pywin in Control Panel's Add or Remove Programs, it is not in the start menu, and I don't know where to find it or how to open.

If my description is too vague to suggest a solution, a useful answer to my query would be diagnostic questions I should be asking.

Thank you.

---

Additional information: 
- I am using windows 10.

- PythonWin is what I want, yes. It is not in the start menu. (I understand now that pywin32 would not show in the start menu.)
- There is a pywin folder on my desktop. One of the subfolders is called Pythonwin. Inside that folder, there is no .exe file. There is a file called start_pythonwin.pyw, but clicking it does not open anything. Based on [this webpage](https://community.esri.com/thread/95711), PythonWin needs to be installed separately. Perhaps that is my situation. But there is no .exe file in this folder. I do not know how to install a program from a folder of files--if that is what I need to do, please provide a reference.
- Before I can automate use of the softare, the tutorial mentioned above provides the following instructions (sorry, it's on the software site and you have to login, so I can't link). I need to open the GUI to do step 1, but I can't open it.

Instructions:

1. Open PythonWin and start the COM Makepy utility from the Tools menu. Locate DesktopController Library in the list of COM interfaces and click OK. This produces the following result.

> ">>> Generating to C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\62401B69-06B2-4C4F-992E-B7A57EFBF059x0x1x0.py
>
> Building definitions from type library...
>
> Generating...
>
> Importing module

2. Press return and then import the COM support module by typing...(at this point, the tutorial explains how to write code to automate the software...)

Comment: I don't understand the question. pywin doesn't show in Add/Remove in my computer. pywin32 is an extension that lets you use Windows API in python, for example you add `import win32gui` in your python code.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani. Actually it does. The installer is an *.exe* (which I think wraps an *.msi*). Now back to the question: what is the problem here? You don't see *pywin32* in *Start Menu*. As Barmak pointed out, a script that contains now that `import` statement will be able to use *pywin32*'s features. Before installation, that script would have failed.

Comment: Ok. I understand that I can use pywin already when writing python code. I need to use PythonWin (the GUI program that comes along with pywin32) and start COM Makepy from the Tools menu.

Comment: @user4396936 check my updated answer.

Comment: And another thing, can you specify what version of Python you are using. Since that Tutorial seems to be oriented for Python 2.7 but you said you installed PyWin32 for Python 3.6, 64 bits. I assumed you were using Python 3.6.

Comment: Yes, using python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select something from the Tools Menu in pywin

I think you mean PythonWin (it comes with pywin32 installer). PythonWin comes with a few tools to use with Pywin32 (it's a GUI program, a Python editor actually and it has a Tools menu). Check your tutorial again and make sure what it is that you're looking for. I could have checked it out, but you didn't provide a link or a quote so it's hard to help you.

Anyway, if it is PythonWin what you are looking for (and I think it is), it should be located [along side Python in your start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbjfD.jpg).

Hope this helps.

---

Ok, now that you have updated your question I can help a bit more.

I don't understand how the installer didn't install PythonWin on your Python Start Menu but ok. Since what you want to do is execute makepy, there is another way to do it besides the PythonWin program.

Go to your `site-packages` folder, then `win32com` and then into the `client` directory. So the path will be something like `C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\`. There you will find a file called `makepy.py` and another called `makepy.pyc`. Either one of those can be used to launch the makepy tool.

Once you have used the makepy tool to create the wrapper to your COM object you can find it in the `gen_py` directory.

You can comment to this answer if you have any questions.